# Is the span of all nilpotent ideals also a nilpotent ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, nilpotence

Given a non-zero Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we define $\mathcal{L}^2 = \big[\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L} \big] = \big\{ [x, y]: x, y\in \mathcal{L} \big\}$, and for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\geq 2$, define $\mathcal{L}^{k+1} = \big[ \mathcal{L}, \mathcal{L}^k \big]$. We call $\mathcal{L}$ **nilpotent** if there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n = \{0\}$, and when $\mathcal{L}$, we call the least $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n = \{0\}$ the **nil-index** of $\mathcal{L}$. For instance, any abelian Lie algebra is nilpotent and their nil-index is $2$.

Now suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a non-nilpotent and non-zero Lie algebra. Suppose $\mathcal{I}$ the family of nilpotent two-sided non-trivial ideals in $\mathcal{L}$ is non-empty. Observe that for any $I, J\in \mathcal{I}$, $I+J$ is also a non-trivial ideal and $(I+J)^3 \subseteq I^2 + J^2 \subseteq (I+J)^2 \subseteq I+J$. Hence $I+J$ is also nilpotent. If the nil-index of $I$ is $n$ and the nil-index of $J$ is $m$, then the nil-index of $I+J$ is at most $\max(n, m)+1$.

Put $\mathcal{J} = \operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{C}} \Big( \bigcup_{I\in \mathcal{I}} I\Big)$. Clearly $\mathcal{J}$ is a two-sided ideal, although it could be the entire $\mathcal{L}$. My questions is: if $\mathcal{J}$ is a proper ideal, is it necessarily nilpotent? If not (i.e. if $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{I}$ or if $\mathcal{J}$ is not nilpotent), can we find a maximal nilpotent ideal in $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: I tried using Zorn's lemma and was blocked by the same problem. Suppose $\{ I_i \}_{i\in \mathcal{A}}$ is a chain ordered by inclusion in $\mathcal{I}$. Then I do not know how to show $\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{A}} I_i$ is nilpotent, and, in this case, one can show that $\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{A}} I_i = \operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{C}} \Big( \big\{ I_i: i\in \mathcal{A} \big\} \Big)$. Perhaps you mean a different order?

Comment: To apply Zorn's lemma, I need to show that the span of infinitely many nilpotent ideals is also nilpotent, which is the problem I cannot figure out. The difficulty is if there is a "uniform" nil-index for a chain (ordered in inclusion) of nilpotent ideals.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I posted the same question in **MO**  and someone provided an example that contains an infinite direct sum of nilpotent Lie algebras $\bigoplus_{k\in \mathbb{N}} L_k$ where the nil-index of $L_k$ is $k$. In this example, for instance, I wonder how to find a maximal nilpotent ideal.